# VBA to reference new sheet daily

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was looking to be able to reference a new worksheet daily within a `VLookup` Code

Currently my code looks as below :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[133],'[Unavista UTI Lookup November2019.xlsm]Nov 28'!C4:C7,4,0)"
```

However each day the date changes within the code. Is there a way I can amend this so each day the Macro will just look for the latest Worksheet with the latest date?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can string in a couple of `Format(Now(),` statements in your code as per below:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[133],'[Unavista UTI Lookup " & Format(Now(), "mmmmyy") & ".xlsm]" & Format(Now(), "mmm dd") & "'!C4:C7,4,0)"
```

Result:
`=VLOOKUP(EH13,'[Unavista UTI Lookup November19.xlsm]Nov 28'!$D:$G,4,0)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but it doesn't seem to be working, seems its now having an issue actually opening the file itself?

Comment: Looks like its having an issue referencing the file which has been quoted within the formula itself.

Comment: In that case you should check if the file you're opening exists with that identical name ad extention, (down to the letter and spaces) and it has that tab in it with that identical name. If even one character is out of place it won't work.

Comment: yep looks to be the correct name, the name of the file itself is hardcoded with the month, so that doesn't need to be formulated to include (Now().

It was more the date of the tab which change daily due to another macro running in the background. 
So something like this.. 
"=VLOOKUP(RC[133],'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]" & Format(Now(), "mmm dd") & "'!C4:C7,4,0)"

Comment: If the name of the tab changes due to a macro running, I'd recommend looking into that macro and see what code it uses to name the tab. Then apply the same to the above, so you're sure to use the correct one each time.

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I took a look into the Macro, and it auto populates the tab name with the below formula from a Range

="'"&TEXT(IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)=1,TODAY()-3,TODAY()-1),"Mmm D")&"'!$D:$J"

With this, is it possible to include that formula within my current Lookup above, so that it can reference the worksheet name correctly?

Comment: All this formula does is format todays date (minus a couple of days) as "Mmm D", which should be mostly the same as what I did in my answer. What does the range "$D:$J" contain? Does it have any influence on your tab name? (if empty, check for spaces at the end)

Comment: Think I have over confused it now. I've simplified the workbook which the formula is referencing, still having an issue finding the latest sheet though with the date format. 
Is there a way to instead reference the latest worksheet which has been created today, rather than the latest worksheet with the FormatNow() date?

Is it possible to make the formula more readable and remove R1C1? 

MyLookupFile = Range("P18")

Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("EH2"), & Format(Now(), "mmm dd") & "'!C4:C7, 4, FALSE"

Comment: Try: `Activecell.Formula = "=VLookup(EH13," & "'[" & Range("P18").Value & "]" & Format(Now(), "Mmm D") & "'!C4:C7, 4, False)"`

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt seem to be working...

I've hardcoded the file being referenced as MyLookupfile

Rather than looking for a specific date within the worksheet name, is it possible to just look for the latest created tab, so it looks like something along the lines of the below? (Note - i've used latestcreatedtab as a sub for now).
Formula still needs work but just trying to show what i am aiming to get too

Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("EH2"),[MyLookupFile & LatestCreatedTab], C4:C7, 4, 0)